# Javascript/Node.js server - querying dataset in JSON file to create URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, server, localhost

**Application desc:**

I'm trying to create an HTML template which takes in an array of card objects and uses the data contained within to generate a page to display the list of cards. For each card in this list, I'm supposed to have a link that points to the URL for that specific card (e.g., http://localhost:3000/cards/that_card’s_id) and the link text should indicate the card’s name and unique ID.

Basically, I would type node server.js in my cmd bar and then open google chrome and type localhost:3000 in my address bar, and it would take me to the cards html page which displays all the links. When I click on a specific card, it should take me to another html page that just displays text showing the card name and cost of the card.

**Problem:**

I created a server. The problem is, **when I type in localhost:3000 in my address bar, the page doesn't seem to load.** I can't even test to see if my code works as the page doesn't load at all. The page just says "This page isn't working" and "localhost didn’t send any data." I was told it's because in my server code, I'm listening for request urls `/cards` , `/cards/` and `/cards?` . When I try to access `localhost:3000` , the request url is `/` , so I am trying to access a url that I am not handling.

server.js:

```
const pug = require("pug");
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
const url = require('url')

let cardData = require("./cards.json");
let cards = {}; 
cardData.forEach(card => {
    cards[card.id] = card;
});

//Initialize server
const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    if (request.method === "GET") {
        if (request.url === "/cards") {     
              response.statusCode = 200;
              response.write(pug.renderFile("./views/cards.pug", { cards: cards }));
              response.end();
        }else if (request.url.startsWith("/cards/")) {
            const paths = request.url.split("/");
            const cardId = paths[2];
            if (cards.hasOwnProperty(cardId)) {
                const targetCard = cards[cardId];
                response.statusCode = 200;
                response.write(
                    pug.renderFile("./views/card.pug", { card: targetCard })
                );
                response.end();
                return;
            } else {
                response.statusCode = 404;
                response.end();
                return;
            }
        } else if (request.url.startsWith("/cards?")) {
            const params = request.url.split("?");
            const [_, value] = params[1].split("=");
            const limit = parseInt(value);
            if (limit < 1) {
                response.statusCode = 400;
                response.write("Invalid query");
                response.end();
                return;
            }
            const responseCards = Object.values(cards).slice(0, limit);
            response.statusCode = 200;
            response.write(
                pug.renderFile("./views/cards.pug", { cards: responseCards })
            );
            response.end();
            return;
        }
    } else {
        response.statusCode = 404;
        response.write("Unknown resource.");
        response.end();
    }
});

//Start server
server.listen(3000);
console.log("Server listening at http://localhost:3000");
```

cards.json:

```
[
    {
    "artist":"Arthur Bozonnet",
    "attack":3,
    "collectible":true,
    "cost":2,
    "flavor":"And he can't get up.",
    "health":2,
    "id":"AT_003",
    "mechanics":["HEROPOWER_DAMAGE"],
    "name":"Fallen Hero",
    "rarity":"RARE"
    },

    {
    "artist":"Dan Scott",
    "attack":3,
    "collectible":true,
    "cost":4,
    "flavor":"Is he aspiring or inspiring? Make up your mind!",
    "health":5,
    "id":"AT_006",
    "mechanics":["INSPIRE"],
    "name":"Dalaran Aspirant",
    "rarity":"COMMON"
    }
]
```

cards.pug:

```
html
    head
        title Cards
body

    div#main
        h1 List of Cards:
        each card in cards
            a(href="/cards/" + card.name) #{card.id}
            br
```

card.pug:

```
html
    head
        title #{card.name}
body

    div#main
        h1 Name: #{card.name}, Cost: $#(card.cost)
```

Comment: Please try to keep the problem statement small crisp and clear. It should not be too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a solid reason for not using `express` or equivalent webserver framework, and although I would strongly recommend using such a tool for all but the smallest of use-cases, I'll still attempt to point you in the right direction given your current setup.

**You have no route handler for "/":**
The reasons the server hangs when you go to localhost:3000 is that the request handler function doesn't have any behaviour for "GET /".
You should see your response if you instead visit `localhost:3000/cards`

**Serving the card by id:**
The best approach (given the technical constraints) to serve the card by id is something like this (rest of code ommited for brevity):

```js
} else if (request.url.startsWith("/cards/")) {
      const paths = request.url.split("/");
      const cardId = paths[2];
      const card = cards.find((card) => card.id === cardId);

      if (!card) {
        response.statusCode = 404;
        response.end();
        return;
      }

      response.statusCode = 200;
      response.write(pug.renderFile("./views/card.pug", { card: card }));
      response.end();
      return;
    }
```

**General Approach**
Again, I would seriously consider using [express](https://expressjs.com/), it would force you to divide your code into more readable fragments and make your life **much** easier if your project continues to grow. By way of example this is how some of your code would look in express:

```js
const app = require("express")()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile("./views/home.pug")
})

app.get("/cards", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile("./views/cards.pug")
});

app.get("/cards/:id", (req, res) => {
  const card = getCard(req.params.id);

  if (!card) {
    return res.sendStatus(404)
  }

  return res.sendFile("./views/cards.pug", {card })
});
```

This code isn't complete - but I hope it shows you how much cleaner your server could look! I do hope it helps - and best of luck writing your app